# How to retrieve desiredKeys for CloudKit notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push, cloudkit

I've setup CloudKit to store and send notifications for changes in a table called "Notifications" which is working great. However, I'm handling the subscriptions based on the content of a field I've simply named "key" (imaging subscribing to different threads), also working great.

Now I want to include the content in the field "key" in the payload, as per the property "desiredKeys", but it's not included in the regular payload in UNNotificationCenter willPresent method (just the regular alert, badge and sound keys are present, not the "key" field.

I've setup my CKNotification.Info as follows:

```
let querySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Notification", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", key), options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
        let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
        info.titleLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
        info.titleLocalizationArgs = ["title"]
        info.subtitleLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
        info.subtitleLocalizationArgs = ["subtitle"]
        info.alertLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
        info.alertLocalizationArgs = ["body"]
        info.desiredKeys = ["key"]
        info.shouldBadge = true
        info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
        info.soundName = "default"
        querySubscription.notificationInfo = info
```

Title, subtitle and body are working, but desiredKeys are not present.

I'm a bit confused though, as I've read that I'm supposed to create a CKQueryNotification from the dictionary received in didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate method in AppDelegate, but that method is never called, only the one in UNNotificationCenter.

What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data was included in the UNNotificationCenter willPresent method, but not within the "aps" dictionary of the payload. Along side this, there is also a "ck" dictionary containing a bunch of stuff:

```
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String: Any]
        var local = true
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
            local = false
            if let badgeCount = aps["badge"] as? Int {
                if badgeCount == 0 {
                    return // Don't notify on badge reset
                }
            }
        }
        var notificationKey = ""
        if let ck = userInfo["ck"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let qry = ck["qry"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let af = qry["af"] as? [String: Any] {
                    if let key = af["key"] as? String {
                        notificationKey = key
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So, you have to drill down inside ck / qry to find your desired keys.

Yes, the code above is not good looking, but I still found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String: Any]
    var notificationKey = ""
    if let ck = userInfo["ck"] as? [String: Any] {
        if let qry = ck["qry"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let af = qry["rid"] as? String {
                    notificationKey = af
            }
        }
    }
    print("notification key = \(notificationKey)")
```

Mine works just like you described, only got a bit different for the "ck" path, so I need to print the **userInfo** first to get the right path